# Type of Integral question and source

Tags: definite-integrals

[image]

in the question number 13 is an integration question, i am curious to know if there is a similar kind of questions like that that doesn't state the equation but only uses f(x), do you guys know what to search on the internet to find similar questions? and what methods can i use to solve it

Comment: I believe these are called recursive functions, though I may be wrong.

Comment: Observe that if you take the derivative then the integral goes away. (This doesn't always happen, here it happened because the integral in the integral equation had constant limits). Now solve the differential equation that you get from that, then plug it back into the integral equation to find the constant of integration.

Comment: In general this is an integral equation, but you may get rather overwhelmed if you try to look that up in general.

Comment: i still can't figure out how the answer is -1, all i get is (3x-f(x))/2

Comment: $f'(x)=3$ so $f(x)=3x+C$, then $3x+C=3x+2\int_0^1 3t+C dt=3x+3+2C$, solve that equation for $C$, then you can just integrate normally. (Note that the question used sloppy notation by using the same variable name inside and outside of the integral sign.)

Comment: thank you very much @Ian